# Autiloader and PHP session crushing in two applications on the same server

Tags: php, class, session, autoloader

I had one problem with [Autoloader function](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)  in PHP when I was switching between two applications which has same framework and share the same session (because they are on the same server, etc. localhost).

Autoloader actually kept searching for classes (models and libraries) from another application (from one that I opened in same browser before current one), and throwing an error that mentoned class couldn't be found in this aplication.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with simple deleting all the cache from browser (actually only cookie with PHP_SESSION information needs to be deleted).

Does anyone know why is this happening and how to prevent it?

Thanks